# how do I add equal gap on each side of the text with css?

Tags: html, css, text, center

I want to change from this https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6DlX.png to this http://prntscr.com/o9hfh
How do I add the extra gap on both side and squeeze the text together more? basically I want to center the text without useing text-align:center because I like text-align:left better, but if I do left the text will not be in the center anymore.

HTML

```
<body> <!-- start of the body-->
            <ul class="sidemenu">
                <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="">FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href="">How To Order</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Term And Agreement</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Shipping Information</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="about-us">

            <p><h2>About Us</h2>Lorem ipsum .<br />

Morbi in libero quis quam consequat malesuada..</p>
            </div>

            </body>
```

css:

```
#about-us {
margin: 10px auto;
background-color:#FFF;
height:800px;
width:710px;
left:125px;
position: relative;
padding:0em 0em;

}

#about-us p {
text-align:left;
padding-top: 20px;

}

body {
position:relative;
}

.sidemenu{
position:absolute;
background-color: #fff;
width:240px;
height:780px;
margin-top: 10px;
list-style:none;
text-align:left;
padding-top: 20px;


}

.sidemenu li a{
color:#222222;
padding: 0em 1em;
line-height: 2em;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add padding to the #about_us box while slice its width and height accordingly:

```
#about_us {
           padding:20px 40px;
          }
```

and configure line-height for the p label:

```
#about_us p {
       line-height:40px;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try `padding`

```
 #about-us p {
   padding: 0 2% (or px, ems if you prefer);
 }
```

Alternatively, you can use `margin` in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Use right-left padding.

Something like that:

```
#about-us p {
padding: 20px 20px 0  20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a padding on your paragraphs to achieve more spacing to the sides:

```
#about-us p {
    padding: 0 40px;
}
```

note that this is a [shorthand](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp) for:

```
#about-us p {
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

squeeze the text together using

```
line-height:15px
```

and simply use margin or padding for arranging

Answer (score 0):

Don't put your h2-tags (or any header tags for that matter) inside a p-tag.

Slap some padding on the div#about-us